# Getting error when initializing core data context

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, environment-variables

I want to simply store a string array in core data and read it when I try and init the context I get the error "Variable 'self.context' used before being initialized". How can I fix this?

I think this is because the appDelegate hasn't be init, but it's an environment object that gets init in my main class initializer.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import CoreData

struct MyView {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init() {
        context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    func createStock(stockArray: [String]) {
        let newStock = Stock(context: context)
        newStock.stockArr = stockArray as NSObject

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving Stock: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func fetchStocks() -> [Stock] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Stock> = Stock.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let stocks = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return stocks
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching Stocks: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you make `context` a computed property?

Comment: Because `appDelegate` wasn't initialized at this time. Changing `context` to computed property or `persistentContainer` to a store property in `MyView` and then using it directly without `appDelegate` should fix this.

Comment: @jnpdx thanks using it as a computer property fixed it like so **var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }**

Comment: In SwiftUI it's recommended to create the Core Data stack in a separate class and put the context into the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the error "`Variable 'self.context' used before being initialized`" occurs because `self.context` is being assigned a value within the initializer before `self.appDelegate` has been initialized, hence the context cannot be properly set at this point.

[jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342520/swift-getting-error-when-initializing-core-data-context#comment136349249_77342520) to change `context` to a [`NSManagedObjectContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) computed property is a valid one, since it makes sure that `context` is derived from `appDelegate` whenever it is accessed, rather than trying to set it during initialization (which does lead to the error mentioned).

```swift
struct MyView {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

```bash
+-------------------------+
|       MyView            |
| +---------------------+ |
| | AppDelegate Adaptor | |
| +---------------------+ |
| +---------------------+ |
| | Computed Property   | |
| |   context           | |
| +---------------------+ |
+-------------------------+
```

On the other hand, [son](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3214202/son) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342520/swift-getting-error-when-initializing-core-data-context#comment136349266_77342520) that the error is because `appDelegate` was not initialized at this time, which aligns with the original issue.
See also "[How to configure Core Data to work with SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-configure-core-data-to-work-with-swiftui)" from [Paul Hudson](https://twitter.com/twostraws) for illustration, using [`NSPersistentContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer).

```swift
struct MyView {
    var store: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.store.viewContext
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

```bash
+------------------------------+
|       MyView                 |
| +--------------------------+ |
| | NSPersistentContainer    | |
| +--------------------------+ |
| +--------------------------+ |
| | NSManagedObjectContext   | |
| | (from store.viewContext) | |
| +--------------------------+ |
+------------------------------+
```

Both suggestions essentially serve to *delay* the access to `appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext` until *after* `appDelegate` has been initialized.

jnpdx's suggestion is simpler and more direct, while son's suggestion provides a way to encapsulate the `NSPersistentContainer` within `MyView` itself, avoiding the dependency on `appDelegate`.

---

The last approach, [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342520/swift-getting-error-when-initializing-core-data-context/77342864#comment136350366_77342520) by [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) is to separate the Core Data stack into its own class and passing the context into the environment.

- It keeps the Core Data setup and management separate from your SwiftUI views. That separation makes the code more organized, easier to understand, and easier to maintain.
- By encapsulating the Core Data stack in its own class, you can reuse it across different parts of your app without duplicating code.
- SwiftUI provides the environment as a way to share data across views. By placing the `NSManagedObjectContext` in the environment, any view can access the context and perform Core Data operations.

First, create a separate class for the Core Data stack:

```swift
class CoreDataStack {
    static let shared = CoreDataStack()
    
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```

Next, in your main SwiftUI file, you can inject the `NSManagedObjectContext` into the environment:

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, CoreDataStack.shared.context)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `ContentView` and all its subviews can access the `NSManagedObjectContext` through the environment, and perform Core Data operations as needed.

```bash
+----------------------------+
|    CoreDataStack           |
| +-----------------------+  |
| | NSPersistentContainer |  |
| +-----------------------+  |
| +------------------------+ |
| | NSManagedObjectContext | |
| +------------------------+ |
+----------------------------+
         |
         | (shared instance)
         v
+----------------------------+
|        MyApp               |
| +------------------------+ |
| | Environment            | |
| | (managedObjectContext) | |
| +------------------------+ |
+----------------------------+
         |
         | (environment injection)
         v
+---------------------+
|     ContentView     |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

---

> When I use the first approach as a computed property, I get the error:
>
> ```
> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; 
> make sure to publish values from the main thread 
> (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
> ```
>
> on the `appDelegate`.
> I think I have to use `DispatchQueue` but not sure how to implement it. Any tips?

It means a SwiftUI view is attempting to update its UI from a background thread. In SwiftUI, all UI updates must be done on the main thread. That is a common issue when working with Core Data and SwiftUI, especially when Core Data operations are performed on a background thread.

To make sure Core Data operations and subsequent UI updates are performed on the main thread, you may need to use [`DispatchQueue.main.async`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300095-async).

```swift
struct MyView {
    // rest of your code

    func createStock(stockArray: [String]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let newStock = Stock(context: self.context)
            newStock.stockArr = stockArray as NSObject

            do {
                try self.context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Error saving Stock: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchStocks() -> [Stock] {
        var stocks: [Stock] = []
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Stock> = Stock.fetchRequest()

            do {
                stocks = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching Stocks: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        return stocks
    }
}
```

In `createStock`, `DispatchQueue.main.async` is used to make sure the Core Data operations are performed on the main thread.
Same for `fetchStocks`: `DispatchQueue.main.sync` is used to make sure fetching from Core Data occurs on the main thread.

The `DispatchQueue.main.async` method schedules a block of code to be executed on the main thread at a later time, which can be useful for operations that update the UI. On the other hand, `DispatchQueue.main.sync` schedules a block to be executed on the main thread and waits for it to complete before continuing, which can be useful for operations that need to return a value.

Comment: When I use the first approach as a computed property I get the error "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates." on the appDelegate. I think I have to use DispatchQueue but not sure how to implement it. Any tips

Comment: @ahmed Note: I have also included the third approach.

Comment: I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: would you look at this, its tricky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472276/swift-scncamera-lock-globe-rotation-around-axis